# fprintf printing weird characters when used with a batch file redirection

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, printf

I have a batch file as follows

```
wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed > file.txt
program
```

program is the executable of the following command

```
gcc -o program initial_scan.c -lpsapi
```

following is the initial_scan.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#define DIV 1048576
#define WIDTH 7

int main(){


     MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
     statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
     GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);

     PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION statex2;
     statex2.cb=sizeof(statex2);
     GetPerformanceInfo(&statex2,statex2.cb);


     FILE *f=fopen("file.txt","a");
     if(f==NULL){
        printf("error opening the file");
        exit(1);
     }


     fprintf(f,"There is  %*ld percent of memory in use.\n",WIDTH, statex.dwMemoryLoad);
     fprintf(f,"There are %*I64d total MB of physical memory.\n",WIDTH, statex.ullTotalPhys/DIV);
     fprintf(f,"There are %*I64d free  MB of physical memory.\n",WIDTH, statex.ullAvailPhys/DIV);

     fprintf(f,"There is %*d processes currently in the system. \n",WIDTH,statex2.ProcessCount);
     fprintf(f,"There is %*d threads currently in the system. \n",WIDTH,statex2.ThreadCount);

     return 0;


}
```

when I run the batch file the output is as follows

```
CurrentClockSpeed  
3101               
桔牥⁥獩†††㈠‵数捲湥⁴景洠浥牯⁹湩甠敳മ吊敨敲愠敲††〸㈷琠瑯污䴠⁂景瀠票楳慣⁬敭潭祲മ吊敨敲愠敲††〶〲映敲⁥䴠⁂景瀠票楳慣⁬敭潭祲മ吊敨敲椠⁳††〱‱牰捯獥敳⁳畣牲湥汴⁹湩琠敨猠獹整⹭ഠ吊敨敲椠⁳†ㄠ㘳″桴敲摡⁳畣牲湥汴⁹湩琠敨猠獹整⹭ഠ
```

when i compile and run the initial_scan.c file without the wmic command i get the correct output which i expected from initial_scan.c file. what is the issue in the batch file?

Comment: Never mind the batch file and redirecting output to a file.  What happens if you open a command line session, execute the wmic command without the redirection, and then run `program`?

Comment: then it works fine. but i need to write the output of the wmic to the same file

Comment: It looks like C uses a different character encoding than cmd, so the output of `program` is not being displayed correctly. i.e. cmd is outputting to the file first, and so dictates the encoding method.

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. You could prove my guess true or false, buy editing the batch script to run `program` before the `wmic` command. That way at least the output of program should be readable.

Comment: Maybe the EOF marker's causing you trouble, try using a+ instead of a for the fopen. See [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)

Comment: Or try to output to `stdout` and run smth like `program >> file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening / writing your file using ANSI encoding, wmic outputs UTF-16 though, here's the fixes you need to take:

Add this to your file opening:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "a, ccs=UTF-16LE");
```

And replace your `fprintf` like this:

```
fwprintf(f,L"...\n", ...);
```

Comment: This fixes the proble, and explains why my earlier implementation did not work.thanks

Answer (score 0):

okay I was able to fix the problem by editing the batch file as follows

```
program
wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed >> file.txt
```

> > ">>" Appends the command output to the end of a file without deleting the information that is already in the file